# Disabling Dialogue prompts in ubuntu

Tags: dialog

I switched from Windows to Ubuntu a while ago now, but various popup dialogue boxes that prompt for confirmations continue to irritate me. Especially the ones when closing a Terminal that's running another process ("Close This Terminal?: There is still a process running in this terminal. Closing the terminal will kill it." Cancel | Close Terminal), the one about updates that runs intermittently on start up ("Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore"), and the one when I connect my phone ("You have inserted a digital media player").

Is there a way to simply disable all pop-up dialogue boxes?

I'm using 11.10 due to a compatibility issue I had with 12 and a general dislike of 13.

Comment: Your question is off topic because 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) is not supported any more, and has not been since May. Take a look at both [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) and [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) which are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot simply disable all dialogs that may pop up.

Comment: Thanks for reply. And the three specific ones I mentioned?

Comment: There should be a "do this always" checkbox on the digital media dialog. The others cannot be disabled.